# Как узнать наибольшее и наименьшее число из массива?

Tags: c, массивы

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

int main() {
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
int i, n, m = 0, g = 1;
int* a;
printf("vvedide dlinu masva: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
a = (int*)calloc(n, sizeof(int));
printf("vvedide vash massiv: ");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i-1] < a[i]) {
        m = a[i];
    }
}
if (m != 0) {
    printf("\n%d", m); // наибольшее число массива
}
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (a[i - 1] > a[i]) {
        g = a[i];
    }
}
if (g != 0) {
    printf("\n%d", g); //Наименьшее число из массива
}
}
```

Мне нужно определить максимальное и минимальное число из массива. При введенных числах. 5(Длинна массива), 1 2 3 4 5 (значения массива) выводит все нормально, мах -5, min - 1. А при последовательности 5 4 3 2 1 выводит только min 1, мах не выводит, потому что он остается 0. Но как мне проверить max в таком случае?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не правильный алгоритм нахождение максимума и минимума

Вы сравниваете число и его соседа, а надо с минимальным найденым на текущий момент

```
int min = a[0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if (a[i] < min){
        min = a[i];
    } 
}
```

Comment: А зачем еще раз сравнивать с `a[0]`? Очевидно же, что при `i=0` сравнение будет ложно.

Answer (score 2):

Что за бредовый поиск минимума/максимума?

Для массива  `int a[n]`

```
int max = a[0], min = a[0];
for(int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
{
    if (min > a[i]) min = a[i];
    if (max < a[i]) max = a[i];
}
```

Все.